# Using boost to generate random numbers between 1 and 9999

Tags: c++, boost, random

How can i used boost library in C++ to generate random numbers between 1 and 9999

Comment: You need to use the modulus operator `%` (think a  little bit). And you might not need boost, just use the standard `random()` or `lrand48()` functions.

Comment: Go and read the boost documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_random.html and come back with an actual question when you've actually tried something and gotten stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try googling for "boost random number" first? Here's the relevant part of their documentation [generating boost random numbers in a range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_in_a_range)

You want something like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
std::time(0) gen;

int random_number(start, end) {
  boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(start, end);
  return dist(gen);
}
```

edit: this related question probably will answer most of your questions: [why does boost::random return the same number each time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845456/boostrandom-generate-the-same-number-every-time)